# Ruby on Rails Undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was going to create a link to a controller's action `update_heimdall` here is the code:

`app/controller/admins_controller`:

```
  def heimdall
    @headline = "Heimdall"
    @users = User.where(deleted_at: nil)
    authorize @users
    @focusUser = params['users'].blank? ? current_user : User.find(params['users'])
    heim = Heimdall.new
    @cards = heim.get_cards(@focusUser.trello_id, @focusUser.trello_access_token, @focusUser.trello_secret_token)
  end

  def update_heimdall 
    @user = params['users'].blank? ? current_user : User.find(params['users'])
    authorize @user
    heim = Heimdall.new
    heim.update_cards(@user.trello_id, @user.trello_access_token, @user.trello_secret_token)
  end
```

`app/views/admins/heimdall.html.rb`:

```
<%= link_to "Odśwież", update_heimdall(), class: "btn btn-warning" %>
```

I am enclosing as well listing from rails routes command:

```
heimdall GET    /heimdall(.:format) admins#heimdall                                        
update_heimdall GET   /heimdall/update_heimdall/:id(.:format)   admins#update_heimdall
```

Unfortunately this code causes the following error:

> undefined method `update_heimdall'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in your code, convert heim in to an instance variable `@heim` so that you can access it in views. then call specifiy the object in action path.

When you performed `rake routes` you will get all the `paths` on left side

```
heimdall GET    /heimdall(.:format) admins#heimdall                                        
update_heimdall GET   /heimdall/update_heimdall/:id(.:format)   admins#update_heimdall
```

therefore your code should be:

```
<%= link_to "Odśwież", update_heimdall_path(@heim), class: "btn btn-warning" %>
```

for more information you can checkout this ruby on rails guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Also, the route requires an `:id` to be passed. Your code will still error out.

Comment: I got what was the problem. I didn't add _path at the end, my bad. Thank you.